# Unable to connect to Azure Synapse DB via JDBC using authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword

Tags: maven, jdbc, java-8, azure-active-directory, azure-synapse

I am running into an issue while trying to connect to Azure Synapse DB using JDBC and authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword.

I am using Java 8 for development. Below are the pom dependencies I am using:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>9.4.0.jre8</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
     <artifactId>msal4j</artifactId>
     <version>1.11.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here's the code I am using for connecting to Synapse DB:

```
SQLServerDataSource sqlServerDataSource = new SQLServerDataSource();

sqlServerDataSource.setServerName("someserver.database.windows.net");

sqlServerDataSource.setDatabaseName("somedbname");

sqlServerDataSource.setUser("someuser@some.com");

sqlServerDataSource.setPassword("somepwd");

sqlServerDataSource.setAuthentication("ActiveDirectoryPassword");

sqlServerDataSource.setEncrypt(true);

sqlServerDataSource.setTrustServerCertificate(true);

sqlServerDataSource.setUseBulkCopyForBatchInsert(true);

Connection connection = sqlServerDataSource.getConnection();
```

Here's the MSFT link I was referring to for the above code:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15#connecting-using-activedirectorypassword-authentication-mode

The issue is, the call to `sqlServerDataSource.getConnection()` is failing with the below error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Failed to authenticate the user someuser@some.com in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword). javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getCorrectedException(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:228)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthToken(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:65)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getFedAuthToken(SQLServerConnection.java:4751)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.onFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:4724)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.processFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:4680)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onFedAuthInfo(tdsparser.java:289)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:125)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:5560)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4289)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:88)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:4227)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7417)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3488)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2978)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2628)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2471)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1470)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:1317)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnection(SQLServerDataSource.java:100)
```

**I am not sure if I need any other dependencies besides the 2 mentioned above.**

If anyone has faced a similar issue and would like to share their solution, it would really help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error, the problem seems to be with user account or certificate so Please try to use, like this **sqlServerDataSource.setTrustServerCertificate(false)**; in your code and try connecting

And make sure to  set the azure ADadmin for your server
In the azure portal>>search for sql servers>>and click on your server and go to active directory admin under the settings>> select Set admin.>>  In the Add admin page, search for a user, select the user or group to be an administrator, and then Select>> At the top of the Active Directory admin page, select Save.(The changes will take several minutes)

Other option is like you can use contained user, for this a contained user database must exist and a contained database user representing the specified Azure AD user or one of the groups, the specified Azure AD user belongs to, must exist in the database, and must have the CONNECT permission. For this you need to create a contained user and you need to map the user to azure AD.

Reference [Create contained users mapped to Azure AD identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-users-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities)